# How to embed third party js library (BoxCast) into Polymer 3.0

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-3.x

I'm trying to include the BoxCast JS API (http://boxcast.github.io/boxcast_js_docs/examples/) into my polymer 3.0 web application as a third party library.

Ive managed to get the starter script / example from the above link running as a stand-alone html/js. But if I try to embed it in a Polymer Element the boxCast player fails with an `Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Document': '[object HTMLDivElement]' is not a valid selector` error.

**Basic html - loads the player successfully**

```html
<div id="testplayer"></div>
<script src="https://js.boxcast.com/v3.min.js"></script>
<script>
boxcast('#testplayer').loadChannel('vgniwkahiegcflco2pq6', {
  autoplay: false,
  showTitle: true,
  showDescription: true
});
</script>
```

**Embedded in Polymer - doesn't work**

```js
import { PolymerElement, html } from '@polymer/polymer/polymer-element.js';
import './shared-styles.js';

import 'https://js.boxcast.com/v3.min.js';

class AruBoxCastPlayer extends PolymerElement {
  static get template() {
    return html`
      <style include="shared-styles">
      </style>
      <div id="testplayer">
        loading boxcast player
      </div> 
    `;
  }

  static get properties() {
    return {
    };
  }

  _loadBroadcast() {
    console.log("load broadcast");
    console.log('test node binding', this.$.testplayer.textContent);

    boxcast(this.$.testplayer).loadChannel('vgniwkahiegcflco2pq6', {
      autoplay: false,
      showTitle: true,
      showDescription: true
    });
  }

  ready() {
    super.ready();
    this._loadBroadcast();
  }
}

window.customElements.define('aru-boxcast-player', AruBoxCastPlayer);
```

My assumption is that I do something wrong with passing the `div`-element to the boxcast-js - as also the error message implies, but I can't figure out how to solve this issue. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use the es-6 way of importing libraries...

```
# First, install the SDK from NPM
npm install boxcast-sdk-js --save

# Then, in your javascript project:
import boxcast from 'boxcast-sdk-js';
```

I'm not sure this will work but similar libraries like animejs, and jquery are updating to ES-6 and import similarly

```
// example
import anime from 'animjs';
import * as $ from 'jquery';
```

and from looking at the changelog they just updated their get* methods to ES-6...

http://boxcast.github.io/boxcast_js_docs/changelog/

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion - your answer definitely gave me a starting point. Unfortunately with this approach I have to build/include an additional player since the sdk doesn't support this functionality - and IMO the documentation could be a bit more detailed...

Comment: When I started polymer 3, I was also reluctant to build especially because of the build issues that come with the polymer CLI, but i then discovered that angular has no problem using polymer 3 in its application and very easily builds both itself along with the polymer custom elements. Angular uses webpack...In any case, using build scripts is just a boiler plate hurdle that once overcome leaves to the back of your mind...especially with IDE's that can be configured with watchers that automate your build and run process

Answer (score 0):

I don't know boxcast.

However, based on the first code :

```
boxcast('#testplayer').loadChannel
```

And the error returned in your polymer attempt, looks like **boxcast** method expects a string that allows it to locate the element that will be the base for it.

However, in the polymer version:

```
boxcast(this.$.testplayer)
```

You are using $.testplayer that is not a string, but already an element.

May be you can call directly loadChannel on this element

```
this.$.testplayer.loadChannel (.....
```

Failing that, you should see in the boxcast docs how to skip the first step (trying to locate the element)

Failing that, you could go along the first idea (call boxcast('#id') but the element should be probably in lightdom and not in shadowdom

Why is this the case ? - the message error states

> > Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Document'

So the library is trying to find the element starting from **document**. Since the polymer element will be rendered in shadow-dom, it is not accesible from the root of the document.

Setting the element with the id testplayer outside of the polymer element, and the assigning it a slot inside the element should make it accesible from the document, but rendered inside the element.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions - Ive tried them unfortunately without the expected result:
1. True - though if I just add the ID-string, BoxCast can't find the element
2. this doesn't work since the div element is not an instance of BoxCast
3. unfortunately the doc is not really helpful
4. could you please clarify why it should be a lightDOM or why this could solve the issue?